# Clicking through multiple javascript links with webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

So heres the thing I have to do. I want to go to a site like http://www.walmart.com/catalog/allReviews.do?product_id=16561041
and expand all the reviews on the page. I require the reviews to be fully open because I need to collect this data. My current code works but is extremely slow.

```
public void clickAllLinks(String linkText){
    for(int j = 0; j < 20 ; j++){
        try{
        if(driver.findElement(By.linkText("(read full review)")).isDisplayed())
            driver.findElement(By.linkText(linkText)).click();
        }catch(NoSuchElementException e){break;}
    }
}
```

Im using selenium 2.21 with firefox driver. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am fairly new to using selenium so my knowledge of it is fairly limited compared to most of you out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`driver.findElements()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) instead of `driver.findElement()`. Then simply click all links one by one in loop.

If this will not help - try to profile you code. Also you can write some js to click all links.

Comment: Thank you, that was so simple and yet it sped things up to 1/10th the time of the original